# Azure external GIT deployment wont ask for credentials

Tags: git, azure, codebase

I just create a website in Azure but i have problems while setting up the GIT deployment. I selected the "Set up deployment from source control"  in the menu and picked type "External repository". At the moment i have all my repos at "codebase". So i selected an external GIT repo. The problem is that the creation wont ask for an username and/or password. Due this reason i have errors on the clone.

```
DEPLOYMENT FAILED: woensdag 18 december 2013 14:22 
Fetch from https://username.codebasehq.com/projectname/projectname.git
ID: temp-1db5d AUTHOR: N/A
DEPLOYED BY: username.codebasehq.com
```

And the Azure deployment log:

```
remote: Authentication Required
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://username.codebasehq.com/projectname/projectname.git/'

D:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe fetch external --progress
```

Comment: interesting. have you tried specifying the external resource in the format `https://username:password@username.codebasehq.com/..` ? If not, try and update here the result, please.

Comment: For an url to ask for an authentication, it should be like: `https://username@username.codebasehq.com/projectname/projectname.git` (or with user/password: `https://username:password@username.codebasehq.com/projectname/projectname.git`)

Comment: When i tried that the interface will tell me "Invalid repository url"

Answer (score 1):

Note that even if it worked, External Repository would not cause automatic deployments when you push changes to codebase, and you need to click a Sync button in the Azure portal.

Kudu (the git engine in Azure) has some basic Codebase support ([here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/blob/master/Kudu.Services/ServiceHookHandlers/CodebaseHqHandler.cs)), but no support in the Azure portal. It is possible to manually set it up, but there are a number of steps involved (some related info [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Continuous-deployment)). Do note that this is not officially supported in Azure, and you may be the first to try it :)