# Automatic deployment of Azure function is not performed

Tags: git, azure, azure-functions, continuous-deployment

According to [the official Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-continuous-deployment#set-up-continuous-deployment), I have set up deployment from 'External repository (Git or Mercurial)' where I have sources for two Azure functions.

I have expected that it is now configured to be rebuilt when a change is performed to configured branch (in my case branch named source on GitHub) automatic redeployment is performed.

When I make the change to the branch redeployment is not performed - it is required to click [Sync button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iX2KY.png) to get latest data and even when I do it and then I hit [Download app content button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oG3GB.png) **I don't get the latest version of the code - Why?**

How to set up the deployment to be automatically rebuilt?
I don't want to use GitHub deployment, because it requires a write access to the private repositories, that I don't want to allow.

Comment: I just have found that External repository would not cause automatic deployment:https://stackoverflow.com/a/20697635/3529135

Is there any other way how to set up an automatic deployment only with read permissions?

Answer (score 0):

What about utilizing [Deploy Keys](https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/managing-deploy-keys/#deploy-keys) for your GitHub repository?
You can manage keys for your repo on:
`https://github.com/yourName/repo-name/settings/keys`

From docs:

> Deploy keys with write access can perform the same actions as an organization member with admin access, or a collaborator on a personal repository.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not possible to use Deploy keys when using Github deployment. Authorization dialog provides only Login and Password option. So You can use OAuth keys instead of a password - but it is for all the repositories (incl. private ones) in it not possible to generate one per repository